# C# Winforms BackgroundWorker copy and change file System.IO.__Error.WinIOError

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io, backgroundworker

I have a windows forms application with a backgroundworker (bgw).
This bgw does some tasks, within these tasks, there are these:
step 2 - Copy files from one folder to another, using the following code:

```
    public static void CopiarArquivos()
    {
        string fileName;
        string sourcePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        const string targetPath = @"C:\CWEB\CwebIntegracaoMovel";

        if (sourcePath == targetPath) return;

        string destFile;

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location: 
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
            //Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {

            //});
            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist. 
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(s);

                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                if (!ArquivosIguais(s, destFile) &&
                    (!fileName.Contains("WizardIntegracao.exe") ||
                    (fileName.Contains("WizardIntegracao.exe") && !File.Exists(destFile))))
                {
                    fi.CopyTo(destFile, true);
                    //File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                    //new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(
                    //    System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { destFile }).Demand();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The copy works fine (there are some lines commented out as I've tested some other things)
In the step 4 of the bgw, I change some setting on a .config file that was copied on the step 2, with the following code:

```
public static void AlteraBaseAddress(string porta)
    {
        string path = "C:\\CWEB\\CwebIntegracaoMovel\\ServicoIntegracao.exe.config";
        string conteudo = File.ReadAllText(path);
        int inicio = conteudo.IndexOf("http://");
        int fim = conteudo.IndexOf("/ServicoIntegracao/Servico");
        conteudo = conteudo.Remove(inicio, fim - inicio);
        conteudo = conteudo.Insert(inicio, String.Format("http://localhost:{0}", porta));

        File.WriteAllText(path, conteudo);
    }
```

When I run my application, I get the exception:

```
Ocorreu um erro no processo de instalação do serviço:
O acesso ao caminho 'C:\CWEB\CwebIntegracaoMovel\ServicoIntegracao.exe.config' foi negado..
   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   em System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   em System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append)
   em System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   em System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
```

While the error is happening when trying to change the content of the .config file, as far as I've could research, the error is happening while copying the files, they get locked by my own application, and then I can't overwrite it's content.

Does anybody knows how to make this work?

Comment: You should translate the exception into English, don't understand a word it said.

Comment: @HansPassant this .config file is not of the main application that I'm running, it's of a Windows Service that my app installs (among doing some other things)

Comment: @KingKing sorry for not translating it to English, it's this "The access to the path '...' was denied..."

Answer (score 0):

To change the application configuration you should be using the System.Configuration.Configuration class.

There is a full example on how to do this with the Save method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134088.aspx

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: I actually did not try using the Configuration class, but did try to instantiate a XmlDocument to manipulate the attributes and save it with xmlDoc.Save(...);
I'll try your suggestion... Thanks...

Comment: it did work to change the connectionString, but since this file is a windows service config file, I couldn't find out how to change other tags within it. I'd like to change the baseAddress attribute. I'll do some search on this...